# different manifest for debug build and release build

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to use different manifests for the **debug** and **release** builds of my 3 flavours, how can I do this?

```
android {
  productFlavors {
        flavor1 {}
        flavor2 {}
        flavor3 {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio two flavors with different manifest files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478110/android-studio-two-flavors-with-different-manifest-files)

Comment: did you read the question, I need for build types not flavours

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29317682/8089770

Comment: thanks that might work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so I found two ways,

1) create release/debug folder under appname/src folder and keep the different manifests there.

as pointed by Vishva Dave is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29317682/8089770

2) set the release/debug manifest in buildtypes of build.gradle, similar to the suggestion by Jeelan but for build types and not flavors

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
            debuggable true
            **manifest.srcFile['src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml']**
        }
```

Comment: Hi. Can you give simple example(step by step)?

Answer (score 3):

To use another manifest file for particular build the procedure is as follows:

In App build.gradle[ie.Module App] under sourceSets add like this:

```
 sourceSets {
       // Default
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }

    // Custom
     flavor3 {
          manifest.srcFile['src/another_manifest_path/AndroidManifest.xml']
          ...  
          ..other
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if it works.